# Safari not loading iFrame from file same server

Tags: reactjs, iframe, coldfusion

I'm including React project in my ColdFusion website and rendering it inside an iFrame, so the styles in the React project does not affect the current style in ColdFusion.

The index.js in React was set to load the DOM in `<div id="iRentHome"></div>`

LoadReact.cfm

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<cfquery name="getKey" DATASOURCE="myDB">
    SELECT * From System WHERE Id = 1
</cfquery>
<cfset key = getKey.EncryptKey />
<cfset local.pID = encrypt(session.PropertyID, key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX") />
<cfset local.uID = encrypt(session.UserID, key, "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "HEX") />

<body>
    <cfoutput>
        <input type="hidden" id="reactPropertyID" value="#local.pID#" />
        <input type="hidden" id="reactUserID" value="#local.uID#" />
    </cfoutput>
    <div id="iRentHome"></div>

    <!-- The Home Page --->
    <script src="./React/home/js/2.7e3dd526.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./React/home/js/3.f7f3f573.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./React/home/js/main.1609c55d.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./React/home/js/runtime-main.6760acc2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./React/home/css/2.6de17b2d.chunk.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./React/home/css/main.c72b7ad5.chunk.css">
</body>

</html>
```

Then, in the main.cfm file, I call the `LoadReact.cfm` inside an iFrame.

```
<iframe id="homeiFrame" src="./LoadReact.cfm" frameBorder="0" style="width: 1000px; height: 1500px"></iframe>
```

It works perfectly in FireFox and Chrome, but Safari is not rendering the iFrame content. It just shows an empty iFrame and no errors in the browser console.

Comment: This is likely a browser issue and nothing to do with ColdFusion or ReactJS. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/323539/external-content-wont-load-in-iframe-in-safari

Comment: I agree. The link you sent is about external content. I'm trying to load an internal content. It's my own files